# How to change build path on Qt creator

Tags: qt

I am struggling to change the build path on Qt creator 4.0.
I've tried everything, but it keeps compiling in a folder in my documents, when my project is actually on my desktop.
Does anyone have a fix ? Thanks

Comment: In QtCreator there is the Projects tab on the left, where you can change the build folder

Answer (score 1):

You can either add somthing like this into your .pro file;

```
DESTDIR = %{sourceDir}/outDir
OBJECTS_DIR = %{sourceDir}/outDir/obj
MOC_DIR = %{sourceDir}/outDir/moc
RCC_DIR = %{sourceDir}/outDir/rcc
UI_DIR = %{sourceDir}/outDir/ui
```

This should re-direct all the build files into a folder called "outDir" within your source folder (i.e. where your .pro file lives). Note you can use "../" or any absolute path if you really want.

Alternatively you can change the settings in your .pro.user file (which are not part of the config controlled files). To do this you need to edit the build settings in qt creator. You will find an output path that you can change in there. Note you will need to change the path for release and debug builds and also do this for every different build config (e.g. arm-gcc, mingw-gcc, etc...).

Comment: That's a bad idea, because a `.pro` file should be completely agnostic of where the output goes. To direct the output, run `qmake` in the build directory.

Comment: @KubaOber Well, its semi-agnostic in that this is a relative path. But it seems to be the only way to ensure each developers build runs in the same way... other then making a .common.pro (I think its called) file.... but this is even more difficult since you have to manually copy the bits that you want from the user.pro file :(  ... unless you can suggest a better way?

Comment: The build should run the same no matter what output folder you choose, and the choice is made by running qmake in the build folder, as happens after you select the build folder in Qt Creator. You can build the huge project that Qt itself is in any build folder - I'm sure your project can, too. The destination folder should be left to each developers' discretion.